# Externalized Grails 3 Spring Security Config

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am working on externalizing the .YML file in Grails 3.x. The code to make this work, is as follows:

In my Application.groovy, I am implementing the setEnviroment method form the EnvironmentAware interface.

```
@Override
void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
    try {
        String configPath = System.properties["local.config.location"]
        def ymlConfig = new File(configPath)
        Resource resourceConfig = new FileSystemResource(ymlConfig)
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean ypfb = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean()
        ypfb.setResources(resourceConfig)
        ypfb.afterPropertiesSet()
        Properties properties = ypfb.getObject()
        environment.propertySources.addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("local.config.location", properties))
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("unable to load the external configuration file", e)
    }
}
```

I have edited the bootRun task in the build to this:

```
bootRun {
    jvmArgs = ['-Dlocal.config.location=external-config.yml']
}
```

When printing out the values in the setEnvironment method, the properties are indeed being read and added from the loaded object.

Now, for the fun part. When I add this code to my original application.yml file:

```
---
grails:
    plugin:
        springsecurity:
            securityConfigType: 'InterceptUrlMap'
            interceptUrlMap: [
                {pattern: '/**',               access: ['permitAll']}
            ]
            providerNames: ['ldapAuthProvider', 'anonymousAuthenticationProvider']
            ldap:
                context:
                    managerDn: 'uid=admin,ou=system'
                    managerPassword: 'secret'
                    server: 'ldap://localhost:10389'
                authorities:
                    groupSearchBase: 'ou=Groups,dc=aye,dc=com'
                    retreiveGroupRoles: true
                    retreiveDatabaseRoles: false
                    groupSearchFilter: 'member={0}'
                search:
                    base: 'ou=Users,dc=aye,dc=com'
            password:
                algoritham: 'SHA-256'
---
```

Everything works just fine. When I cut and paste it out into the external yml file, I get this beautiful error in Firefox.

[image]

I can tell that the configuration is correct in the provided code, as I can add more roles and filters, and everything works just fine when in original application.yml file. It is only when reading from the external file does this fail. If I remove the security code from both .yml files, .ofc, my page looks strange but the firefox error disappears.

Has anyone got an idea as to why this can be the case?

Comment: We do exactly the same thing but using Groovy external file instead of YML and it works without issues. I'm not expert on YML but maybe something is incorrectly merged into config there.

Comment: yea, i am really not sure to be honest. maybe something is triggering it to not be interpreted as a resource that can be used

Comment: @droggo are your files also named the same?

Comment: No, groovy files does not need to be named the same

Comment: thats just even more weird

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can attempt to test if it will work, is rename your external-config.yml file to application.yml. I believe that the default name should be application, unless otherwise specified.

[This article here shows a good example of its correct use](https://leanpub.com/grails-goodness-notebook/read#leanpub-auto-use-different-external-configuration-files)

When you do that, try to read the properties in one of your classes, to make sure that the yml files are merging. You can read these properties using a command like this:

```
grailsApplication.config.getProperty("grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType")
```

Or, you can print out all of them, using the Holders utility

```
def config = Holders.config
```

Comment: that seems to fix my merging issue. Hm, interesting.

Comment: That is excellent! Sometimes it just takes a little help from a outside source.